# display: inline-block is overriding my div containers

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put 2 containers next to each other. They have a thick white border. They are hidden until a click event that shows them. The containers have class set to hidden. But in order to get the div containers next to each other, I use inline-block. It works great, but now at page load, you can see the border for the divs is visible, because inline-block is overriding it. Help! They were hidden fine before I used inline-block, but couldnt get the div containers next to each other.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What code are you using to un-hide them on the prescribed **Click** event?  Set them to `hidden` in the css, then set them to `inline-block` upon the **Click**.

Comment: I actually used this advide and hid the containers before the click event and it worked. Thank you!